# unable to communicate with payment gateway

Tags: magento, paypal

I used magento v1.9.0.1,i set up my paypal(for testing) setting well, sandbox is off, SSl is off. But still im getting this error: Unable to communicate with the PayPal gateway any help plz?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running into the POODLE issue.  See the details here:  https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-ssl-error-poodle-vulnerability/

Specifically...

> If you want to use TLS 1.2 you’ll need to upgrade to OpenSSL 1.0.1 as a minimum, and then you’ll be able to set CURLOPT_SSLVERSION to 6 (TLS 1.2).
>
> If you want TLS 1.2 to be used automatically during SSL requests, you’ll also need to upgrade to PHP 5.5.19+ (this is the ideal solution but many projects are still on older PHP versions).